# SQL Server succeedes creating a stored procedure that invokes a NON-EXISTING function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, compilation

Tested on SQL Server 2017. If I create a procedure (either in SSMS or sqlcmd) containing a static SQL command referencing a **non-existing function**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mytest
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tableVar TABLE(FIELD_1 INT, FIELD_2 VARCHAR(10))

    -- I am referencing a function that does not exist
    INSERT @tableVar 
        SELECT * FROM dbo.I_DO_NOT_EXISTS()
END
GO
```

Return message is:

> Commands completed successfully.

This is quite an odd behaviour!

Only when I try to run `mytest` I get the error:

```
exec dbo.mytest
```

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.mytest, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 16]
> Invalid object name 'dbo.I_DO_NOT_EXISTS'.

While if I try to compile a procedure calling a non-existing function with `exec`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mytest
AS
BEGIN
    -- I am executing a function that does not exist
    EXEC dbo.I_DO_NOT_EXISTS
END
GO
```

I get a warning **at compile time**

> The module 'mytest' depends on the missing object 'dbo.I_DO_NOT_EXISTS'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.

The latter response seems the correct approach to me.

Is there any option to enforce existence checks on functions referenced by SQL commands?

Comment: That's the way it works; creating a stored procedure in SQL Server doesn't "compile" it - it just creates the DB object. Only when you first **execute** it will the query optimizer in SQL Server attempt to "compile" it (e.g. create an execution plan for it) and only then will existence of functions or other procedures it calls be checked. **CREATING** the stored procedure **DOESN'T** "compile" it ....

Comment: This behavior is known as [deferred name resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#deferred-name-resolution). It's a curse or a blessing depending on the use case.

Comment: But if I invoke a nonexistent function with EXEC I get a warning (at least). That means SQL Server performs a check when I create the stored procedure.
Why invoking a nonexistent function in static SQL is allowed. I would expect the same behaviour both invoking with EXEC and SQL.

Comment: As, for some reason, Microsoft decided that for `EXEC` statements the existance should be checked. Perhaps because people didn't want to be warned about referencing a temporary tables? Though you *can* create temporary stored procedures too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If SP validation is your objective. You can do it after SP is created. After SP is created find all the objects which are referenced by SP. Then check if the referenced object exists or not.

Run following query after SP creation and check for refrenced_id is NULL or not. If it is null then that particular object does not exists and you will get object not exists error during SP execution. Hope this helps! I did a small test, please find code below:

```
CREATE PROC TestSP
AS
BEGIN
    -- SPLIT function does not exists in the Database
    select * from  dbo.SPLIT('a,b,c,d',',')
    --Salary Table exists in the Database
    SELECT [Name],[salary]  FROM [dbo].[salary]
END

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(d.referencing_id) AS referencing_name, o.type_desc referencing_object_type,
 d.referenced_entity_name, d.referencing_id,d.referenced_id
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies d 
JOIN sys.objects o ON d.referencing_id = o.[object_id]
Where OBJECT_NAME(d.referencing_id) like '%TestSP%'
```

[Click to see the Output of above query as Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaK78.png)

Comment: Please put the code as text instead of an image.

Comment: I found a similar answer here:
https://michaeljswart.com/2009/12/find-missing-sql-dependencies/
Actually there are many versions around the web, taking into account synonyms and other peculiarities of SqlServer.
Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I can't vote for it :-)